# Can't understand PHP code snippet using call_user_func

Tags: php

Here is the snippet:

```
class A
{
    static function bar()
    {
        echo get_called_class(), "\n";
    }

}


class B extends A
{
    static function foo()
    {
        call_user_func(['parent', 'bar']);// B why?
        call_user_func([parent::class, 'bar']); // A
        call_user_func(parent::class . '::bar');// A

    }

}
```

- Why does `call_user_func(['parent', 'bar'])` return `B`?
- What is the difference between `['parent', 'bar']` and `[parent::class, 'bar']`?

Comment: I can't explain why the first one returns B, but under PHP 8 that code gives a _'Deprecated: Use of "parent" in callables is deprecated'_ message, so that can probably be considered one of those rather "hazy" language features that was not well defined or gave undesirable results, and has been taken care of now.

Comment: I can also confirm the first one returns B, always. Therefore the explanation I can give is that this is implementation specified. In short, it must ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the latest PHP version you may see this deprecation message:

> Deprecated: Use of "parent" in callables is deprecated

And some more details of the deprecation you can find already here:

- [PHP RFC: Deprecate partially supported callables](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecate_partially_supported_callables)

I don't find this easy to answer, but this is how I understand it: As "parent" is a string only and a generic name its meaning (which concrete class) depends on context.

I suspect `get_called_class()` is therefore incompatible with it and can't resolve the class context as you have expected it.

When you use `parent::class` PHP can resolve the context properly to the concrete class name, therefore using it with `call_user_func()` does not have this ambiguity or context problem.